# how can i read last line of file

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I tried this after reading the file programe get closed. it is not showing the last line of file, which should be in the new1 string pointer after complete reading.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () {
std::string line;
int i;
std::string *new1;
new1 = new string;
ifstream myfile ("path.txt");
   while (myfile)
   {
         getline (myfile,line);
         cout << line<<endl;
         new1=line;

   }              
   cout<<new1<<endl;
   myfile.close();
      cin.get();
      return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: About question: Also tell what it does print...

Comment: Your problem is, the "last line" in the logical flow of your program is the part *after* the last newline, even if that is empty. So you need to decide what "last line" means when file ends in newline, and what it means when last line has "missing" newline.

Comment: That doesn't compile. `z.cc:15:14: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ in assignment
          new1=line;`

Comment: `new1=line;` and `cout<<new1<<endl;` doesn't make sense. `new1=&line;` and `cout<<*new1<<endl;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main change to your code:

Replace

```
while (myfile)
{
     getline (myfile,line);
     cout << line<<endl;
     new1=line;

}
```

by

```
while (getline (myfile,line))
{
   cout << line<<endl;
   new1=line;
}
```

The reason the first one does not work is that after you have finished reading the last line, `while (myfile)` continues to evaluate to `while(true)`. At that time, `getline(myfile, line)` doesn't succeed. You are not catching that return value and dealing with it properly.

Other improvment:

Replace

```
std::string *new1;
new1 = new string;
```

by

```
std::string new1;
```

Not sure why you thought you needed `new1` to be a pointer. If you continue to keep `new1` as a pointer, you'll have to change the `while` loop to:

```
while (getline (myfile,line))
{
   cout << line<<endl;
   *new1=line;  // *new1, not new1.
}
```

Of course you'll have to add a line to delete `new1` too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the last value comes in line before terminating the loop is eof.

use this:

```
while (getline (myfile,line))
{
    cout << line<<endl;
    new1=line;

}
```